# How to return a column name based on conditions in a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe :

| id | Statement_1 | Statement_2 | Statement_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| abc | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| efg | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |

I want to create a new column based on the condition, if a row have a 1.0, it return the column name associate with it.

More clearly, I would like this dataframe in return :

| id | Statement_1 | Statement_2 | Statement_3 | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | Statement_2 |
| abc | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | Statement_1 |
| efg | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | Statement_3 |

Thx to everyone who can help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

Use `idxmax` if you are sure to have at least 1 per row:

```
df['Condition'] = df.filter(like='Statement').idxmax(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
    id  Statement_1  Statement_2  Statement_3    Condition
0  xyz          0.0          1.0          0.0  Statement_2
1  abc          1.0          0.0          0.0  Statement_1
2  efg          0.0          0.0          1.0  Statement_3
```

A more robust way for case where there are 0, 1 or more 1 in the row:

```
df['Condition'] = df.filter(like='Statement').melt(ignore_index=False) \
                    .query('value == 1').groupby(level=0)['variable'] \
                    .apply(', '.join)
```

Comment: *"if a row have a 1.0, it return the column name associate with it"* but if not? And if multiple?

Answer (score 0):

If possible multiple `1` values use matrix multiplication with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Statement')
df['Condition'] = df1.astype(bool).dot(df1.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
    id  Statement_1  Statement_2  Statement_3    Condition
0  xyz          0.0          1.0          0.0  Statement_2
1  abc          1.0          0.0          0.0  Statement_1
2  efg          0.0          0.0          1.0  Statement_3
```

---

```
print (df)
    id  Statement_1  Statement_2  Statement_3
0  xyz          0.0          1.0          1.0
1  abc          1.0          0.0          0.0
2  efg          0.0          0.0          1.0


df1 = df.filter(like='Statement')
df['Condition'] = df1.astype(bool).dot(df1.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
    id  Statement_1  Statement_2  Statement_3                Condition
0  xyz          0.0          1.0          1.0  Statement_2,Statement_3
1  abc          1.0          0.0          0.0              Statement_1
2  efg          0.0          0.0          1.0              Statement_3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to get the names of columns which have 1.0, You can try this:

```
mask = df[["Statement_1","Statement_2","Statement_3"]].eq(1.0).idxmax()
df['Condition'] = df.columns[mask+1]

#output
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lzSk.png]